# How do I filter my custom post types by taxonomy with checkboxes?

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to filter my posts from a custom post type called 'courses'. I've created a custom taxonomy called 'course_types' which has 2 terms; 'Bundled Courses' and 'Single Courses'. I have a form with checkboxes, with which I would like to filter the custom posts, and have used a variety of combinations of tax_query operators ("AND, OR, NOT IN, etc"), but I am unabke to acheieve the expected results. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

The Query

```
<?php
$args = 
    array(
        'post_type' => 'courses',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'course_types',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $_GET['course_types'],
            ),
            'relation' => 'AND',
        ),
    )

 ?>
```

Form with checkboxes

```
 <form method="GET">
  <?php $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'course_types',
    'hide_empty' => false,
  ) 
);
 foreach($terms as $term) {
     echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="course_types[]" value="' . $term->name 
.'">' . $term->name . '</label>';
} ?>
<input type="submit" value="Filter">

</form>


<?php
```

The Results

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'courses' );
}
} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
                        
?>
```

[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was that form was returning a name ('Single Courses' and 'Bundled Courses'), bu the query was expecting a term_id.

Corrected code

```
<form method="GET">
<?php $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'course_types',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
foreach($terms as $term) {
     echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="course_types[]" value="' 
. $term->term_id .'">' . $term->name . '</label>';
} ?>
<input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The query must contain a conditional if not filtered. I used a ternary.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'course_types' ); 
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
$args = 
array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'course_types',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $_GET ? $_GET['course_types'] : $term_ids,
        ),
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ),
);

?>
```